# Replace substring inside a string with a new GUID for each substring found

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a body of text with multiple `<p>` tags. I would like to insert a GUID for each occurrence of the P tags inside this body of text.

Initially I was doing this `text = text.Replace("<p>", "<p data-paragraph-id=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ">");`

But, as you can see this would put the same GUID for each of the P tags. My question is: how can I insert a unique GUID for each occurrence of the P tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or its static veriosn) that allows to return custom result for each match:

> string Replace(string input, MatchEvaluator evaluator)
>
> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a string returned by a MatchEvaluator delegate

Sample:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "<p>", _ => 
       "<p data-paragraph-id=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ">");
```

Side note: if you are trying to modify HTML consider reading with HTMLAgilityPack and adding attributes via DOM... Safer/more extensible than any RegEx/string replace/concatenate you can come up with.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about HTMLAgilityPack. It looks like something I can definitely use!

Comment: Never heard of `Regex.Replace` before, interesting

Comment: One small suggestion perhaps, and that is to include quotes in the result: `"<p data-paragraph-id=\""+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\">"`

Comment: -1 for suggesting Regex. Why not just go straight to HtmlAgilityPack in your answer? Do so and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I'm fine with -1 :) - the question talks about replace and *happen* to use HTML as sample. So whenever someone will try to find this question it is less likely to be hit on HTML rather than regular string processing... (And I'm too lazy to put good HtmlAgilityPack sample... maybe some day).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: the question uses the ASP.NET tag, so it doesn't _happen_ to use HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ method to do what you want:

```
var parts =
    text
        .Split(new string[] { "<p>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .SelectMany(x => new []
        {
            x,
            "<p data-paragraph-id=\"" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "\">"
        })
        .ToArray();

var result = String.Join("", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1));
```